# How can I match this exact phrase with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

[See it in action!](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYMG/)

### HTML:

```
<input type='text' value="2012-12-30 Morning">
<input type='text' value="2012-12-30 Lunch">
<input type='text' value="2012-12-30 Dinner">
<input type='text' value="2012-12-30 Either akgalkgalkgla">
<input type='text' value="2012-12-30">
<input type='text' value="Morning">
<button>Check</button>
```

### Javascript/jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("input")
        .filter(function() {
            return this.value.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+/);
        })
        .css("border", '1px solid red');

})​
```

I tried using the anchors `^` and `$` but it doesn't match it anymore. In the above example, it should NOT match "2012-12-30 Either akgalkgalkgla"

Here's the regex
`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+`

```
2012-12-30 Morning
2012-12-30 Lunch
2012-12-30 Dinner
2012-12-30 Either akgalkgalkgla
```

**Update:**

So `^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+$` does work. I was initially trying this on regexpal, and it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question instead of linking jsfiddle.

Comment: Try using http://regexpal.com/ to work it out, it's my first port of call for JS Regex.

Comment: @Qoop to be fair the usage of regex (with those 3 or 4 different functions) in JS has its own oddities ;)

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is also a must. See the quick tutorials and reference there - they'll probably help you out pretty fast.

Comment: @m.buettner It's in the jsfiddle link. I thought that would actually be more helpful to have it all interactively there.

Comment: @Strawberry If I add anchors to your code, it doesn't match `2012-12-30 Either akgalkgalkgla` but does still match 3 others. http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYMG/3/

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski What the heck. I kept adding that and testing it on Regexpal, and it didn't work. I tried so many other things and I ended up putting on Jsfiddle for this question.

Comment: @Qoop Is there a reason why this might not work in Regexpal? `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+$/`?

Comment: `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\w+$/` works in the JSFiddle for me.

Comment: I think regexpal add it's own '/' (or whatever it uses) so if you get rid of those it may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the anchors seems to work perfectly for preventing partial matches. The contents of the first three inputs are matched, the last three are not:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("input")
        .filter(function() {
            return this.value.match(/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+$/);
        })
        .css("border", '1px solid red');
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYMG/4/

If you want to apply the border to all the elements that *fail* this test, simply invert the boolean you are returning in the filter callback:

```
return !this.value.match(/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anchors works as expected. Are you sure you had the anchors in the right places?

```
/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]+$/
```